# MySQL select as special and the output exclude null version

Tags: mysql

This is my sql statement, as you can see the select SELECT category as special, how can I only get special is NOT NULL.

```
SELECT p.product_id, 

(SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))   
    ORDER BY ps.priority 
    ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special 

FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 

WHERE AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() 

AND p2c.category_id = '20' 

GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC LIMIT 0,5
```

With above statement, I have the following output:
[image]

I tried add the WHERE after the date_available, then I got no result out. I try to use `special` IS NOT NULL it showed: Unknown column 'special' in 'where clause'

Anyone can help in this matter?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The special is an `alias`name which you are assigning to an output of a logic, this occurs after the where clause is executed, so the special column was unknown.**

Try this::

```
Select * 
from
(
SELECT p.product_id, 

(SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))   
    ORDER BY ps.priority 
    ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special 

FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 

WHERE AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() 

AND p2c.category_id = '20' 

GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC 
) mytemp where mytemp.special is not null

LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: not sure, why got people vote you down, I found your solution is best, and explained it well. Thanks! Other also thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Just  use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

```
(SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))   
    ORDER BY ps.priority 
    ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special 

FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
INNER JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 

WHERE AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() 

AND p2c.category_id = '20' 

GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC 
) mytemp where mytemp.special is not null

LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: This query will not solve the purpose, infact it has syntactical error??? Looks like you have copied from my solution..

Comment: @SashiKant I didn't copy your answer . `Inner join` must  work for this purpose because of it except null value . 


Now, According to the creation of GOD we are human being... Right..?? So that as a human being we should use our brain and we must remember that before a Programer we are Human.. So with the crease your knowledge, please increase your sense of humor & Humidity.... Right..Brother, & Never Underestimate anyone... 

If My comment hurts you then I'm Sorry... You can give me Negative Marking, I don't Care... But I Just Tell the truth..

Comment: Strange that we both think of a same `alias name`... But my concern is, your query wont run, please recheck it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set filter on alias something like this :-

```
SELECT user_name AS SPL FROM `apc_users` 
WHERE 1 
HAVING SPL IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY `apc_users`.`user_name` ASC
```

In your case : -

```
SELECT p.product_id, 

(SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))   
    ORDER BY ps.priority 
    ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special 

FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 

WHERE AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() 

AND p2c.category_id = '20' HAVING special IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC LIMIT 0,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this is realy working for you

```
SELECT p.product_id, 

(SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND price IS NOT NULL AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))   
    ORDER BY ps.priority 
    ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special 

FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 

WHERE AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() 

AND p2c.category_id = '20' 

GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC LIMIT 0,5
```